# ResourceInitializationError with Fargate ECS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm fairly new to AWS. I am trying to deploy a docker container to ECS but it fails with the following error:

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 52.46.146.144:443: i/o timeout
```

This was working perfectly fine, until I tried to add a loadbalancer, at which point this error began occuring. I must have changed something but I'm not sure what.

- **The ECS instance is in a public subnet**
- **The security group has in/out access on all ports/ips (0.0.0.0/0)**
- **The VPC has an internet gateway**

Clearly something is wrong with my config but I'm not sure what. Google and other stack overflows haven't helped so far.

**Terraform ECS file:**

```
    resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "solmines-ecs-cluster" {
  name = "solmines-ecs-cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "solmines-ecs-service" {
  name            = "solmines"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.solmines-ecs-cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.solmines-ecs-task-definition.arn
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count = 1

  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.solmines-ecs.id]
    subnets          = ["${aws_subnet.solmines-public-subnet1.id}", "${aws_subnet.solmines-public-subnet2.id}"]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.solmines-lb-tg.arn
    container_name   = "solmines-api"
    container_port   = 80
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb_listener.solmines-lb-listener]
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "solmines-ecs-task-definition" {
  family                   = "solmines-ecs-task-definition"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = "1024"
  cpu                      = "512"
  execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.solmines-ecs-role.arn}"
  container_definitions    = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "solmines-api",
    "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.solmines-ecr-repository.repository_url}:latest",
    "memory": 1024,
    "cpu": 512,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
]
EOF
}
```

Comment: I think you need HTTPS port in the SG as well.